# Configure webpack encore for async and await (Symfony 4 and VueJs)

Tags: javascript, symfony, vue.js, symfony4, webpack-encore

I have installed a VueJs project in Symfony 4 but I was suprise when I was having an error with await and async (Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined)

I find a lot information for webpack but not webpack encore

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5085

What is the config for webpack.config.js with webpack encore (Symfony 4) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
    .configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
        babelConfig.presets = ['es2015','stage-2']
        babelConfig.plugins = ['transform-runtime']
    })
```

All content of file

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    //.createSharedEntry('assets', ['babel-polyfill'])
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // uncomment to create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    // .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment to define the assets of the project
    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('vue', './assets/js/Vue/main.js')
    .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/scss/style.scss')
    .addStyleEntry('css/vue', './assets/scss/vue.scss')
    // uncomment if you use Sass/SCSS files
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .enableVueLoader()
    .enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {}, {
            resolveUrlLoader: false
     })
    .configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
        babelConfig.presets = ['es2015','stage-2']
        babelConfig.plugins = ['transform-runtime']
    })
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Of course you have to install the packages

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-2
npm install babel-preset-es2015 (or es2017)

npm install babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use babel plugin, without changes in webpack config

> babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/

e.g. part of our .babelrc config:

```json
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-async-to-generator"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

```js
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

And this works great with Webpack Encore